# How can I make a Marquee with 3D effects similar that is there in Android website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, marquee

I want to make a 3D marquee like that is there in Android Website (http://www.android.com)

I realized that it's used **-webkit-transform: translateZ** but how can I put it to work?

Comment: i don't understand exactly what you trying to accomplish. can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: If you want to know how a specific site accomplished something. Try having a look at their code. Right click and hit view page source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do complex animations like that, you will need to use the css properties "transform" and "transition" along with the vendor prefixes such as -webkit- and -moz- because these properties are not fully accepted yet.

All you would have to do is setup the html as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="movingDiv"></div
</div>
```

And then for the css:

```
.container{
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
}
.movingDiv{
   position: absolute;
   transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s, left 1s, top 1s;
   opacity: 1;
}
.movingDiv.foreward{
   transform: scale(1.2);
   opacity: 0;
   left: -400px;
   top: 400px;

}
.movingDiv.backward{
   transform: scale(1.2);
   opacity: 0;
   left: 600px;
   top:-100px;
}
```

And then use some javascript to give each of the elements (movingDiv) a class of "backward" or "forward" based on its position and leave it just as the default class (movingDiv) if it is the primary element.

I recommend spending some time reading up on it. One good source is [this site](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/), but there are plenty others.

Comment: Don't feed the help vampires.

Comment: [This Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) may provide some insight.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks Cole. I will keep an eye out for that and try to be more observant.

Comment: Great. Now that you understand, I changed my downvote to an upvote.